# Jboss Deployment Email Exception

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Deployed failed to my wildfly server, anyone has any ideas about this error, org-apache/commons/mail/EmailException ?

> 20:05:10,842 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread
>   1-2) MSC000001:
>
> Failed to start service
>   jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: 
>       org.jboss.msc.service.StartException 
>       in service jboss.deployment.unit."test.war".POST_MODULE: WFLYSRV0153: 
>       Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment "test.war"
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/commons/mail/EmailException
>                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Your application depends on a class that should be provided by the "Apache Commons Email" library but that library isn't included in your application's classpath. How did you compile&package your application? With Maven?

Comment: maven install and wildfly publish.

Comment: Do you have an explicit dependency toward the Commons Email library in your pom.xml? If so make sure it's not scoped "provided", that would tell maven that you expect the server should provide the library, which obviously doesn't happen. You should look for a dependency tag like [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-email/1.5) in your dependencies tag

Comment: please check my edit.

Comment: I've seen your edit, that looks good. Can you check in the resulting war that there is indeed a `commons-email.jar` inside the WEB-INF/lib/ directory? You can open the war as a zip file to make sure (on windows right click the file, open as, chose the archive handler of your choice)

Comment: yes, war > WEB-INF > lib > commons-email-1.4.jar

Comment: OK, so I don't think it can be a problem with the application itself, maybe either a conflict with wildfly's email handling classes or some configuration that excludes the library from the application on the server. Do you have a jboss-deployment-structure.xml in your application? Any other concerning logs before the error itself?

Comment: jboss-deployment-structure.xml has nothing special and no concerning logs before this error. It is the problem of deployment. Can it be crush with Eclipse or Wildfly, I already tried cleaning Wildfly by reset.

Comment: No idea what's wrong honestly. You could add `-verbose:class` to the JAVA_OPTS of your wildfly server to output verbose classloading logs, but I'm afraid you just won't see anything concerning your library. I'm not sure I'll be able to assist further, I hope someone else will be able to. BTW I suggest you specify your wildfly version in your question, you can add another tag with the specific wildfly version (e.g. [tag:wildfly-10]), it may attract more attention

Comment: Further up the log there is likely a full stack trace which would be helpful to see.